# How to stop a scheduled ontick event on Cesium

Tags: javascript, event-handling, primitive, cesiumjs

I have two buttons on my code which will add and delete primitives when clicked. On the other hand, I have an event listener for `onTick` method which will get as an input the active primitive and a variable indicating its index, and is supposed to used that primitive with that particular index for the event.

When I did debugging I saw that although the input argument was updated but the parameter used by the event listener were not updated. And I got the error that the object is destroyed.

Do you know how I can update these arguments or stop the previously scheduled events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[onTick](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Clock.html#onTick) is a Cesium Event with an [addEventListener](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Event.html#addEventListener) function that returns a hook to unsubscribe.  You simply call the return value, later, when you want to end your subscription to that event.

```
var unsubscribe = viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(myCallback);

// ... later ...

// Stop the onTick callback.
unsubscribe();
```